# Deploying to Heroku without a Gemfile

Tags: heroku, bundler, ruby-on-rails-2

I'm working with an old Rails app that was initially built before Bundler and Gemfiles.  Is it possible to push this app up to Heroku without a Gemfile?  The app is in production on the Bamboo Stack and working without one.  I'm trying to add a development environment on the Cedar Stack (Bamboo is now closed) and getting an error:

```
-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Removing .DS_Store files
 !     Heroku push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected
```

Is it no longer possible to push to Heroku without a Gemfile?

I'll [add a Gemfile](http://gembundler.com/rails23.html) if that's what it takes.

Answer (score 0):

The official word from Heroku Support:

> Hi, yes you need a Gemfile for ruby apps; we don't have any gems
>   installed on the base system so that's how you specify them. That's
>   also how we detect it's a ruby app.
>
> Also potentially useful: https://github.com/kch/gemfile-tool